# Не получается записать то, что выходит из массива в переменную

Tags: c++, строки

Хочу записать в переменную то, что получается в цикле.

```
char buff[50];
char str;       
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(buff); i++){
    if (buff[i] >= '0' && buff[i] <= '9')
         strcat( str,buff[i]);                  
}
cout << str;
```

Выдает ошибку:"аргумент типа `char` не совместим с параметром типа `const char*`"

Comment: Вы пытаетесь в символе сохранить строку?

Answer (score 1):

Так сойдет?

```
char buff[50];

// Надеюсь, код для заполнения  buff у вас есть? :)

char str[50] = { 0 };       
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < strlen(buff); i++)
{
    if (buff[i] >= '0' && buff[i] <= '9')
        str[j++] = buff[i];                  
}
cout << str << endl;
```

Ваша ошибка в том, что вы в 1 (один) символ пытались воткнуть целую строку...

Answer (score 1):

Раз у Вас метка c++, то и пишите на с++

```
char buff[50];
std::string sbuff(buff);
std::string str;       
for (int i = 0; i < sbuff.length(); i++){
    if (sbuff[i] >= '0' && sbuff[i] <= '9')
      str += buff[i]
}
cout << str;
```

как по мне, код стал проще и читаемей.

Comment: о, это уже хорошо:)

Answer (score 0):

Функция strcat() принимает два указателя на строки (см. [strcat](http://cppstudio.com/post/695/)) - первый на изменяемую строку и второй на константную строку. Вы же при вызове функции в качестве первого и второго параметра передаете отдельные символы (char), которые, если будут интерпретированы программой как указатели на строки, непременно вызовут обращение по недопустимому адресу памяти 0x000000XX, где XX-код символа.
Для того, чтобы заставить компилятор не ругаться, приведите первый и второй параметры к (char*) и (const char*) соответственно: strcat((char*)str,(const char*)buff[i]); Для того, чтобы исправить баг, который непременно после этого появится, передавайте указатели на корректные строки либо не используйте функцию strcat(), если Вы хотите оперировать отдельными символами.